# Magento 2 : How to remove signout from my account section at header?

Tags: magento2.2, header, toplinks

While customer logged into account it is showing **two sign-out** from header
Kindly check the below default.xml file from my custom theme.

Can you please suggest ? Actually I have used **parent theme as Luma**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">    
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="helpcenter" before="track-link">
        <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Help Center</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact</argument>      
        </arguments>
        </block>        
    </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>        
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer" template="html/footer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
        <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide and show header with respect to customer login/logout

add this in body of file
`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="vendor\module\Block\Headerlinks" name="history-link" after="my-account-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>    
        </referenceBlock>
```

and in file `Headerlinks` add

```
    <?php
namespace vendor\module\Block;


class Headerlinks extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
         array $data = [],
         \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $customer = $this->customerSession->create();
        if ($customer->isLoggedIn()) {
             $link = '<li><a href="' . $this->getUrl('customer/account/') . '" title="Account & Security">Account & Security</a></li>';
             $link .= '<li><a href="' . $this->getUrl('sales/order/history/') . '" title="Purchase History">Purchase History</a></li>';
        return $link;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```